# java replace in files with auto increment

Tags: java, file, replace

I've been looking for easy way to add ID to HTML tags and spent few hours here jumping form one tool to another before I came up with this little test solving my issues. Hence my sprint backlog is almost empty I have some time to share. Feel free to make it clear and enjoy those whom are asked by QA to add the ID. Just change the tag, path and run :)

Had some issue here to make proper lambda due to lack of coffee today...
how to replace first occurence only, in single lambda? in files I had many lines having same tags.

```
private void replace(String path, String replace, String replaceWith) {
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
        List<String> replaced = lines
                .map(line -> line.replace(replace, replaceWith))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Files.write(Paths.get(path), replaced);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Above was replacing all lines as it found text to replace in next lines. Proper matcher with repleace that has autoincrement would be better to use within this method body isntead of preparing the replaceWith value before the call. If I'll ever need this again I'll add you another final version .

Final version to not waste more time (phase green):

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RepalceInFilesWithAutoIncrement {

    private int incremented = 100;
    /**
     * The tag you would like to add Id to
     * */
    private static final String tag = "label";
    /**
     * Regex to find the tag
     * */
    private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<" + tag + " (.+?)/>", Pattern.DOTALL);
    private static final Pattern ID_REGEX = Pattern.compile("id=", Pattern.DOTALL);


    @Test
    public void replaceInFiles() throws IOException {

        String nextId = " id=\"" + tag + "_%s\" ";
        String path = "C:\\YourPath";

        try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(path))) {

            paths.forEach(filePath -> {
                if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {

                    try {
                        List<String> foundInFiles = getTagValues(readFile(filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString()));
                        if (!foundInFiles.isEmpty()) {

                            for (String tagEl : foundInFiles) {
                                incremented++;
                                String id = String.format(nextId, incremented);

                                String replace = tagEl.split("\\r?\\n")[0];
                                replace = replace.replace("<" + tag, "<" + tag + id);


                                replace(filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString(), tagEl.split("\\r?\\n")[0], replace, false);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Finished with (%s) changes", incremented - 100));
    }

    private String readFile(String path)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    private List<String> getTagValues(final String str) {
        final List<String> tagValues = new ArrayList<>();
        final Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            if (!ID_REGEX.matcher(matcher.group()).find())
                tagValues.add(matcher.group());
        }
        return tagValues;
    }


    private void replace(String path, String replace, String replaceWith, boolean log) {
        if (log) {
            System.out.println("path = [" + path + "], replace = [" + replace + "], replaceWith = [" + replaceWith + "], log = [" + log + "]");
        }

        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
            List<String> replaced = new ArrayList<>();
            boolean alreadyReplaced = false;
            for (String line : lines.collect(Collectors.toList())) {
                if (line.contains(replace) && !alreadyReplaced) {
                    line = line.replace(replace, replaceWith);
                    alreadyReplaced = true;
                }
                replaced.add(line);
            }
            Files.write(Paths.get(path), replaced);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a question. See [https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: totaly agree, not a question. My first post here hence reputation is equal to my IQ when somebody wakes me up before 6am so I can't answer my own questions. Still found it worth sharing as I couldn't find good examples on searching in files and do tags modification.

Comment: You can still re-word it as a question, and answer your own question, as suggested in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with Jsoup.

```
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
    import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

    public class JsoupTest {

        public static void main(String argv[]) {

            String html = "<html><head><title>Try it with Jsoup</title></head>"
                            + "<body><p>P first</p><p>P second</p><p>P third</p></body></html>";
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);        
            Elements ps = doc.select("p");     // The tag you would like to add Id to
            int i = 12;
            for(Element p : ps){
                p.attr("id",String.valueOf(i));
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println(doc.toString());
        }   
    }
```